# Fix an html table to a certain size in an email signature

Tags: css, mobile, html-table, html-email

I am trying to make an html signature using a table, however I can't seem to get it to look clean on mobile. I have tried the "Sky's the limit" height at "190px" keeping it from expanding over the entire page in outlook (everyone at this office uses outlook, my code works in most emails but not in outlook for some reason), but it looks funny after opened in mobile. To keep this weird table adjustment from happening, putting the image at 100% width has helped but it expands over the entire page on a normal email and still doesn't look great on mobile. Is there any way I can get my code to look the way I want it to on both mobile and desktop?

At 190px on mobile:

[image]

At 100% on mobile:

[image]

How I want it to look:

[image]

My Code:

```html
<div style="height: 190px; width: 500px; max-height: 190px; max-width: 500px; min-width: 500px;">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="background: none; border-width: 0px; border: 0px; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
<tr><td valign="center" style="padding-top: 0; padding-bottom: 0; padding-left: 0; padding-right: 0px; border-top: 0; border-bottom: 0: border-left: 0; border-right: solid #2b2b2b"><img id="preview-image-url" src="https://i.imgur.com/JeK1isp.png" nosend="1" border="0" height="100%" alt="SkyBound USA"></td>

<td style= "padding-top:0; padding-bottom:0; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px; background: #2b2b2b" >
<td valign="bottom" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; background: #2b2b2b;" >
<a href="https://www.instagram.com/skybound.trampolines/">
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/h7f7fjo.png" nosend="1" border="0" height="30" alt="Instagram">
</a><br>

<a href="https://www.facebook.com/SkyBoundUSA/">
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/MJ35g0C.png" nosend="1" border="0" width="30" alt="Facebook">
</a><br>
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCH0821QeTOByekqpvrAE6pQ">
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/NuZrjP6.png" nosend="1" border="0" width="30" alt="YouTube">
</a><br>
</td>
<td style= "padding-top:0; padding-bottom:0; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px; background: #2b2b2b;" >

<td style="padding-top: 0; padding-bottom: 0; padding-left: 12px; padding-right: 15px; background: #ebebeb">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="background: none; border-width: 0px; border: 0px; margin: 0; padding: 0; background: #ebebeb;">
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
<a href= "https://www.skyboundusa.com/"><img src= "https://i.imgur.com/Ml3FJ3X.png" nosend="1" border="0" width="90" padding-bottom="5" alt="Facebook"></td></tr>

<tr>
<!-- name goes here -->

<td colspan="2" style="padding-bottom: 3px; color: orange; font-size: 18px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; padding-top: 5px; ">CORINNE NICEWICK</td></tr>



<tr><td colspan="2" style="color: #2b2b2b; font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">

<!-- title goes here --> 
<i>Design and Marketing Consultant</i></td></tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="2" style="color: #2b2b2b; font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
<strong>SkyBound USA</strong></td></tr>


<tr><td width="5" valign="top" style="vertical-align: top; width: 20px; color: orange; font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">p:</td>

<!-- phone numbers go here primary first, then mobile--> 
<td valign="top" style="vertical-align: top; color: #2b2b2b; font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"> 888.891.4689&nbsp;&nbsp;

<span style="color: orange;">m:&nbsp;</span>703.795.7373</td></tr>

<tr><td width="5" valign="top" style="vertical-align: top; width: 20px; color: orange; font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">a:</td>
<td valign="top" style="vertical-align: top; color: #2b2b2b; font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">3140 Warner Ave., Santa Ana, CA 92704</td></tr>
<tr><td width="5" valign="top" style="vertical-align: top; width: 20px; color: orange; font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">w:</td>
<td valign="top" style="vertical-align: top; color: #2b2b2b; font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
<a href="https://www.skyboundusa.com/" style=" color: #23aabc; text-decoration: none; font-weight: normal; font-size: 12px;">www.SkyBoundUSA.com</a></td></tr>
<tr><td width="5" valign="top" style="vertical-align: top; width: 20px; color: orange; font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">e:</td>
<td valign="top" style="vertical-align: top; color: #2b2b2b; font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
<a href="mailto:cnicewick@skyboundusa.com" style="color: #23aabc; text-decoration: none; font-weight: normal; font-size: 12px;">cnicewick@skyboundusa.com</a></td></tr>
<!-- email goes here - replace mailto and name -->

<tr>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td></tr></table>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add your media query as well that changes the look on mobile please?

Comment: Sorry, How do I use a media query? It seems that must be what I'm missing.

Comment: Do a search for `litmus media query` and it will give you a list of articles where you can learn how to do media queries for emails. Also avoid `colspan` as it will break in a few email clients. Once you have everything ready then maybe create a proper question?